# Структурная директива Angular с HostBinding

Tags: angular, директива

В проекте нужна структурная директива, которая по условию изменяет состояние элемента, на который накинута.

Покажу на примере простенькой директивы shimmer:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[shimmer]'
})
export class ShimmerDirective {

    private _shimmer = false;

    @HostBinding('class.shimmer')
    public get shimmerBinding(): boolean {
        return this._shimmer;
    }

    @Input()
    public set shimmer(value: boolean ) {
        this._shimmer = value;
    }

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
}
```

Использую эту директиву вот так:

```
<button (click)="loading=!loading">
    переключить
</button>
{{ loading }}
<p *shimmer="loading">проверка шиммера</p>
```

По идее, после нажатия на кнопку "переключить", на элемент `p` должен навеситься класс `shimmer`, но этого не происходит:

[image: активное состояние директивы]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрана именно структурная директива не просто так, нужна дополнительная обрабатываемая логика, так что способ изменить структурную директиву на атрибутивную не подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любая структурная директива - это просто замаскированный `ng-template`, то есть ваша разметка эквивалентна вот такой:

```html
<button (click)="loading=!loading">
    переключить
</button>
{{ loading }}
<ng-template [shimmer]="loading">
    <p>проверка шиммера</p>
</ng-template>
```

Легко видеть, что любые ваши хост-биндинги тут будут применяться именно к `ng-template`, а не к тому элементу на который вы "вешаете" структурную директиву.

---

Теперь что делать нужно в таком случае. А нужно получить сохранить ViewRef и добавить класс напрямую в rootNodes через Renderer2:

```
    private viewRef: EmbeddedViewRef;

    constructor(
        templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
    ) {
        this.viewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }

    @Input()
    public set shimmer(value: boolean ) {
        this._shimmer = value;
        
        for (const node of this.viewRef.rootNodes) {
            if (value) {
                this.renderer.addClass(node, 'shimmer');
            } else {
                this.renderer.removeClass(node, 'shimmer');
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну и всё-таки рассмотрите возможность сделать свою директиву обычной, а не структурной. Помните, что даже обычная директива имеет доступ к элементу на который её навесили через ElementRef.